# Can't get `post_id` from table `postmeta` in wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I can't get list post_id from table `postmeta`. This is my code.

```
 function getPostID(){
     global $wpdb;
     $ListID =  $wpdb->get_results("Select `post_id` FROM `qan_postmeta` WHERE `meta_value` = 'News'");
 }
```

My query is working with mysql. I change to 'get_var','get_row' but it is not working.

Comment: You can't use existing functions? [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta), 
[get_the_ID](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID)

Comment: I want to get all the ID that `meta_value` = 'News'

Comment: What are you doing with ListID? In your function you're assigning the query result to a variable but not actually returning it.

Comment: Use WP_Query for this. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_value = 0 AND meta_key REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z].*$' ORDER BY `wp_postmeta`.`meta_value` ASC");
print_r($query);
```

wp_postmeta table contains all post metas. We need to select fields starting with chars.(Not "_");

So I use **REGEXP** in sql sentence.
Happy coding.